# Is it possible to load a preformatted WebDataRocks report on component startup when the said report is stored in Sharepoint?

Tags: java, r, sharepoint, shiny, webdatarocks

I have integrated WebDataRocks pivot table into one of our R Shiny applications. This pivot table has a pre-determined format and a dynamic dataset, that is updated in collaboration with the other members of the team. Both the format and dataset files are stored in Sharepoint. My team now wants to be able to open the latest version of the data on component startup rather than having to click in the load button and selecting the report. I have tried to save the link to the file in the argument "*dsource*" and also "report" of the function "*pivta*", but I always received the same error message:
[image]

Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note that using a report from the file on your Sharepoint should be set like this:

```
report: "URL-to-your-Sharepoint"
```

Meanwhile, the link to your dataset should be included into the **report file**. For example,

```
{
    dataSource: {
        filename: "URL-to-your-datasource"
    }
}
```

Considering the error, please check whether there're any errors in the console. If yes, provide us a screenshot of the console window so we could continue the investigation.

Furthermore, you may open an issue on the pivta GitHub: https://github.com/feddelegrand7/pivta/issues